# how can I change only a param like an id in my URL

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a have a list of links inside a childcomponent which is integrated in different pages and if I click on a link, I need to get an id back, but I need to keep the current URL with the new id to call another method.

```
this.$router.push({path: '/page/', params: {id:id}})
this.$router.push({path: '/otherpage/', params: {id:id}})
```

I tried several things which are not working, like

```
this.$router.push({path: this.$router.currentRoute, params: {id:id}})
```

to get the following on different pages

```
http://domain/page/1
```

or

```
http://domain/otherpage/1
```

if I hardcode the path it works with:

```
this.$router.push(`/page/${id}`)
```

but I like to reuse the component on any page

thanks to Igor I ended up with the following:

```
  const path = `/${this.path}/${node.id}`
  if (this.$route.path !== path) this.$router.push(path)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From vue-router docs:

> Note: params are ignored if a path is provided...
> https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

Instead of providing the path, you should call this.$router.push() with the route name, and the desired params.

For your example:

```
this.$router.push({name: this.$router.currentRoute.name, params: {id:id}})
```

This approach assumes that your routes are named, like this:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/page/:id",
    component: () => import('/path/to/component.vue'),
    name: "nameOfTheRoute",
    // other attributes
  },
  //...
]
```

Comment: thanks for your response but then I get : Navigating to current location ("/page/") is not allowed, I added the route definition to my post

Comment: there are some inconsistencies in your routes. the route that is named does not accept params, and the route that accepts params has no name. check into that

Comment: I get the same error if I change all paths to receive the id

Comment: could you console.log the currentRoute object and the id before this.$router.push() is called and post the results?

Comment: updated my post, if you need more of the object I will try to figure out how to copy all from chrome lol, thanks

Comment: I think the error you are getting is linked to duplicate navigation. your currentRoute has the params id = 1 and if you do this.$router.push({name: "page", params: {id: id}) the generated path will be also "/page/1". before pushing, you should check that the params (id) are different, otherwise don't push